# How to mod_rewrite "?u="

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite from

```
https://example.com/plugins/mediaplayer/site/_embed.php?u=57aa2050dcba22df
```

to

```
https://example.com/embed/57aa2050dcba22df
```

This is what im using now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^embed/?$ \/plugins\/mediaplayer\/site\/\_embed\.php [NC,L]
```

Result:

```
https://example.com/embed/?u=57aa2050dcba22df
```

How to rewrite **?u=** ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your hashing algorithm only involves letters a-z and numbers 0-9..

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^embed/([a-z0-9]+)$ plugins/mediaplayer/site/_embed.php?u=$1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It took me quite a bit to figure out good practice for rewrite rules aswell.

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to figure out what the OP was looking for on the first try as the question is using the word "from" and "to" backwards and the "result" snippet doesn't explain if that's the expected or desired result or not.